# Evitar cargar ciertos campos de una consulta eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

estoy haciendo una consulta de esta forma. Para cargar todas ventas  con sus respectivas relaciones, Resulta que todo esta bien.

```html
 $ventas = Venta::with(['categoria','user','foto'])
     ->orderBy('id','DESC')
     ->where('status','PUBLICADO')
     ->paginate(10);
```

pero Quisiera que ciertos campos por ej. de usuario no se cargaran ya que bueno. Cuando le envió a un vista.
solo muestro lo necesario, pero como puedo evitar que no se cargue.
el campo "contraseña del usuario" ?

hice un dd

```
#items: Collection {#546 ▼
#items: array:5 [▶]
```

Y esto me muestra.

Cada venta tiene sus datos. Y todo perfecto. pero . .

```html
0 => Venta {#452 ▼
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: null
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:9 [▶]
        #original: array:9 [▶]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: array:3 [▶]
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #fillable: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
```

estás son sus relaciones .

```html
   #relations: array:3 [▼
          "categoria" => Categoria {#487 ▶}
          "user" => User {#547 ▶}
          "foto" => Foto {#645 ▶}
        ]
```

pero me esta cargando el campo contraseña :(

```html
"user" => User {#547 ▼
            #fillable: array:3 [▶]
            #hidden: array:2 [▶]
            #connection: "mysql"
            #table: null
            #primaryKey: "id"
            #keyType: "int"
            +incrementing: true
            #with: []
            #withCount: []
            #perPage: 15
            +exists: true
            +wasRecentlyCreated: false
            #attributes: array:12 [▼
              "id" => 3
              "nick" => "Taniaƒß"
              "email" => "ejemplo@ejemplo.com"
              "password" => "$2y$10$BaEUQJdHCmZsqIuf0VGbkOdJmYi32kPx/Ce6Azyu.o.Xajtg9DCSS"
              "nombre" => "Tani"
              "apellidoP" => null
              "apellidoM" => null
              "fotoPerfil" => "http://carrefourjeunesse.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/female1-512.png"
              "fechaNacimiento" => null
              "remember_token" => "QSKRWXcCejTA4Px0kWMhmrK3BMgxiSiAKux7yEp7HDOd8xx9YkUu0YiFtK5X"
              "created_at" => "2018-09-12 15:55:57"
              "updated_at" => "2018-09-12 15:55:57"
            ]
```

Comment: No te sirve si te lo propongo sin el uso de eagger loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, la primera es agregar un array de atributos en tu modelo que quieres que se escondan:

```
class User extends Model{

   //......


   protected $hidden = ['password'];
}
```

Lo malo de esta solución es que SIEMPRE te esconderá el campo "password" cuando hagas una consulta. Para que esto funcione deberás de convertir tu resultado a array o a JSON con el método `->toArray()` ó el método `toJson()` respectivamente.

La otra forma es que hagas un select específicamente de las columnas que quieres que se muestren:

```
$ventas = Venta::with(['categoria','user' => function($query){
   $query->select(['id', 'nick', 'email', 'nombre', 'apellidoP', 'apellidoM', 'fotoPerfil', 'fechaNacimiento', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
},'foto'])
                    ->orderBy('id','DESC')
                    ->where('status','PUBLICADO')
                    ->paginate(10);
```

Otra solución que sólo aplica de laravel 5.6 en adelante, especificar las columnas dentro del parámetro de la función `with`:

```
$ventas = Venta::with(['categoria','user:id,nick,email,nombre,apellidoP,apellidoM,fotoPerfil, fechaNacimiento,remember_token,created_at,updated_at','foto'])
                    ->orderBy('id','DESC')
                    ->where('status','PUBLICADO')
                    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Estupendo ahora funciona!

Comment: aunque te diré que  en el modelo, user 

 protected $hidden = ['password'];

está exactamente así pero no lo esconde. pero todos modos he usado otras de las que compartiste

Comment: @AlexBurkeCooper Si, una disculpa, olvidé mencionar algo, debes de convertir el resultado a array o a json para que se escondan los campos `$hidden`, ya actualicé mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el siguente código para hacerlo:

```
$ventas = Venta::with(['categoria','user' => function($query){
   $query->select(['id', 'nick', 'email', 'nombre', 'apellidoP', 
 'apellidoM', 'fotoPerfil', 'fechaNacimiento', 'remember_token', 
'created_at', 'updated_at']);
},'foto'])
                    ->orderBy('id','DESC')
                    ->where('status','PUBLICADO')
                    ->paginate(10);
```